# Missing messages sent from Celery in RabbitMQ queue

Tags: python, rabbitmq, celery

I have a script calling Celery's `send_task` function 3047 times in a specific queue called `vv`. Using `rabbitmqadmin list queues` command, I noticed that only 2870 messages were present in the queue, without any worker connected to the `vv` queue.

Did you experienced this kind of behavior yourself? Is it only a displaying bug from `rabbitmqadmin`?

Thank you in advance for your help, if you need more details about the script I'll complete my question!

Edit: The script looks like this, with a large number of documents and triggered by `celery-beat`

```
from celery import Celery

app = Celery()
app.config_from_object('celeryconfig')

@app.task
def document_monitoring(index, query, kind):
    # generate random messages
    documents = [{'_id': str(i)} for i in range(10000)]

    for document in documents:
        app.send_task(
                "vv_consumer", 
                kwargs=document,
                queue='vv'
        )

    return 0
```

Comment: Please complete your question with a minimal reproducible example.

Comment: I've completed the question with the reproducible example, the number of messages is of that order of magnitude. This process is triggered by a `celery-beat` every minute

Comment: I see nothing wrong with this. Why would you think it is a bug?

Comment: When i'm monitoring the number of messages in `vv` queue, i get less messages than the number of call of `send_task`. Some messages disappeared and are not sent to the queue.

Answer (score 0):

After digging into the logs of my RabbitMQ instance, I discovered that I reached the limits its [Memory Alarms](https://www.rabbitmq.com/memory.html) defined by the variable `vm_memory_high_watermark`. The default value is set to 0.4, meaning that once 40% of the instance RAM is used, RabbitMQ blocks the publishers (like the script in example) and stop receiving new messages. Because of this behavior, I missed several messages originally sent to the queue.

To fix this issue, my solution was to:

- Hardware side: Increase the RAM of my instance
- Software side: Increase the `vm_memory_high_watermark` value to 0.7 (following the [doc](https://www.rabbitmq.com/memory.html#configuring-threshold))